# How to add a Windows 7 partition to grub2's list of available OS?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

I'm not sure how it happened, but I lost the "windows 7" entry from my Grub2 screen after updating ubuntu.

How can I add it ? I knew how to do it in grub legacy, not in grub 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try installing grub-pc tools to automatically detect all available operating systems

```
sudo aptitude install grub-pc
```

and then update grub2 for your next restart

```
sudo update-grub2
```

if Windows is correctly installed it should now be added to grub.cfg

Comment: Doesn't seem to find windows ... arg maybe my partition is corrupted in some way :'(

Comment: In that case I'd backup everything from the Windows partition as soon as possible and reinstall. Can you browse the windows partition when logged in Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, I can see all my files ... my windows partition commited suicide, there's no other explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This article seems to answer the question :

[How to add Vista/Windows 7 partition to Grub 2 (Ubuntu 9.10, Karmic Koala)](http://erickoo.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/how-to-add-vista-partition-to-grub-2-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/)