# Is there a LiveCD which I can use instead of bootloader (scan installed OS, allow to start)?

Tags: boot, multi-boot

My [story](https://superuser.com/questions/820699/rhel-7-windows-server-2008-r2-dual-boot-on-proliant):

- I've installed Windows Server 2008 R2, shrunk some space for Linux
- I've installed RHEL 7 Server to this space
- After that GRUB2 only allows me to start RHEL 7, no option to start Windows. However I can see Windows partition in file manager, so likely I should just add Windows to grub2 somehow.

While I'm investigating this issue (this may take a day, or a week, or a month), can I somehow use "external" bootloader which will allow me to start Windows?

I.e. I expect some disk, which I can boot, which will scan what OSes I have and which allow me to select the OS I want to start from the list of installed OSes.

Comment: Does not re-generating grub.cfg with os-prober installed work? It detects OSs that installed.

Comment: not tried that. I don't have Internet on server, do you know if it's possible to install `os-prober` ON RHEL7 without internet? Anyway it's interesting to know if such disk exist for the case when everything doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you can download `os-prober` using browser on another computer, copy it to your server and install it. Note its dependencies. You can see URL of repository in .repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.